# Query to display the name of the department that has the maximum staff count order by department name

Tags: sql, oracle

```
1 select Department.department_name, count(Staff.staff_id) as counter
2 from Department right join Staff on Department.department_id = Staff.department_id
3 group by department_name
4 order by department_name;
```

The above code is giving me

```
    DEPARTMENT_NAME            COUNTER
------------------------------ ----------
CSE                             2
ECE                             1
EEE                             2
IT                              2
SE                              4
```

But I just need to show the department which has the max value without showing the value like this,

```
DEPARTMENT_NAME
------------------------------
SE
```

Here's the [Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrZ8j.jpg) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

In standard SQL, you would use `order by` and limit to one row:

```
select s.department_name
from Department d join
     Staff s
     on d.department_id = s.department_id
group by d.department_name
order by count(*) desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Notes:

- This works in Oracle.  In MySQL, use `limit 1` instead.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and read.
- An inner join is sufficient.  You don't need departments with no matches.

EDIT:

In older, unsupported versions of Oracle, you can use:

```
select d.*
from (select s.department_name
      from Department d join
           Staff s
           on d.department_id = s.department_id
      group by d.department_name
      order by count(*) desc
     ) d
where rownum = 1;
```

Comment: fetch first 1 row only; not working. Error ORA 00933: SQL command not properly ended.

Comment: @AbhishekMazumder . . . `fetch` is available in all **supported** versions of Oracle.  What version are you using?

Comment: I have tried using rownum and have got the same result but the test cases are still not cleared I guess the platform(that i am using) does not allow using rownum.

Comment: @AbhishekMazumder - so for your ora-00933, we'd need to see your actual, complete, exact statement.  You can't debug code that you can't see, and neither can anyone else.